# Send html/css template by email with Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I made a form to send email on a website built on Laravel. It used to work without problems, but then I added an html/css template to the email. The user should receive an html/css template in the email, but is receiving only text.

This is my send function

```
    public function sendmail(Request $request)
    {
        $str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $request->emails);
        $arr=explode(" ", $str);
        $emails = array_slice($arr, 1, -1);
        $subject = $request->subject;
        $body = $request->body;

        $sent = 0;
        $declined = 0;
        $decEmails=[];

        $send = 0;
        $declined = 0;

        foreach($emails as $email)
        {
           $send = Mail::send(['html' => 'pages.sendemail'],['subject'=>$subject, 'body'=>$body], function($message) use ($email, $subject)
            {
                $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
            });
           if( $send == 1 )
            {
                $sent++;
            }
            else
            {
                array_push($decEmails, $email);
                $declined++;                
            }
        }

        return view('sent', compact('sent','declined','decEmails') );
}
```

and this is my view

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Ebay Georgia</title>  
 <!--<link type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" href="images/icon.ico">-->
 <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
<script>
 document.createElement("header"); 
 document.createElement("nav");
 document.createElement("footer");
 document.createElement("section")
</script>
<style>
*{ margin:0; padding:0}
html, body{width:100%; min-height:100%;}
a{ text-decoration:none;}
li{ list-style-type:none;}
img{border:0;}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Conv_BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight 2012';
 src: url('fonts/BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight 2012.eot');
 src: local('☺'), url('fonts/BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight 2012.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight 2012.svg') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Conv_BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight Caps 2012';
 src: url('fonts/BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight Caps 2012.eot');
 src: local('☺'), url('fonts/BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight Caps 2012.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight Caps 2012.svg') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}

/*main css*/
#wrapper{
 width:92%;
 max-width:600px;
 padding:29px 4% 10px 4%;
 background:#1c75d7 url(../images/corner.png) no-repeat right bottom;
 background-size:auto 100%;
 margin:50px auto; 
}
#maincContent{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
 background-color:#fff;
 margin-bottom:13px;
 position:relative;
 clear:both;
 overflow:hidden;
 border-bottom-right-radius:40px;
}
#head{
 width:92%;
 max-width:550px;
 margin:25px auto;
}
#head h1{
 width:94px;
 height:47px;
 margin:25px 5.45%; 

}
#head h1 a{
 display:block;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat center center; 
}
#content{
 width:92%;
 max-width:550px;
 margin:25px auto;
}
#content h2{
 color:#5c5c5c;
 font-size:15px; 
 margin-bottom:20px;
 font-family: 'Conv_BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight 2012';
 margin:0px 5.45% 25px 5.45%; 
}
#content .parpagraph{
 color:#5c5c5c;
 font-size:15px; 
 margin-bottom:20px;
 font-family: 'Conv_BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight 2012';
 font-weight:600;
 margin:0px 5.45% 25px 5.45%;
}
#content .parpagraphGreen{
 color:#86b817;
 font-size:14px; 
 margin-bottom:20px;
 font-family: 'Conv_BPG DejaVu Sans ExtraLight Caps 2012';
 font-weight:600;
 margin:0px 5.45% 44px 5.45%;
}
#content img{
 display:block;
 margin:0px 5.45% 60px 5.45%; 
}
#maincContent::after {
    content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top:35px solid #dbdbdb;
  border-right: 35px solid #dbdbdb;
#footer{
 width:92%;
 max-width:550px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
#footer ul{
 margin-left:7%;
 overflow:hidden; 
}
#footer ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 width: 31px;
 height:35px;
 margin-right:2%;
}
#footer ul li a{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 text-indent:-9999px; 
 margin-bottom:8px;
}
#footer ul li a.mail{
 background:url(../images/mail.png) no-repeat center center;
}
#footer ul li a.fb{
 background:url(../images/fb.png) no-repeat center center;
}
#footer ul li a.link{
 background:url(../images/link.png) no-repeat center center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <section id="wrapper"><!--id="wrapper"-->
     <section id="maincContent"><!--id="maincContent"-->
         <header id="head"><!--header-->
          <h1><a href="index.html" target="_blank">Ebay Georgia</a></h1>           
         </header><!--End of header-->
         <section id="content"><!--id="content"-->
                <h2> {!! $subject !!}</h2>
                <div class="parpagraph">
                {!! $body !!}     
                </div><br>
                <div class="parpagraphGreen">
                 მადლობა ჩვენი სერვისით სარგებლობისთვის.
                </div>
                <img src="../images/line.png" alt="#" />
             </section><!--End of id="content"-->
           
        </section><!--En dof id="maincContent"-->
        <footer id="footer"><!--id="footer"-->
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#" target="_blank"  class="mail">mail</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="fb">facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="link">link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </footer><!--End of id="footer"-->
    </section><!--End of id="wrapper"-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the question? Could you post a minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the view given to the `Mail::send()` method is assumed to contain HTML. So no need to give `html` key to your view array, this should work:

```
Mail::send('pages.sendemail', ['subject'=>$subject, 'body'=>$body]...
```

But if you want to send a plain text you must define it as `['text' => 'pages.sendemail']`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! Sadly, it didn't help, and I still have the same problem. Could the problem be that gmail is blocking html / css? If so, is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: @Kabaneri I just tested it my self by copying your mail template and save it as `pages/sendmail.blade.php`, and seems to be working for me unless the styling is messed up see https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5kg0i/8ks4

Comment: This is plain html and works for me as well. I have a problem with css styles. The page should look like this. http://imgur.com/mUNhGVZ

By itself, it displays like it should, but when sent by email, it doesn't work.

Comment: So I think the problem is not in Laravel nor Gmail side, it's in your email template, the email rendered as html as you can seen on this [screenshot](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5kg0i/47wg) but the style is broken somehow.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My problem was in css. I had written my html and css separately and it was a problem.
 Thanks for your help.